# How to hide the navigation bar from the initial view screen or on a particular view?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

In my app i hav 4 views, i want to hide the navigation bar only from my initial view, when i tried using this code 
`[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];` it hides the navigation bar of other views too., plz help me to fix this issue ,.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

add above code in `-(void)ViewWillAppear` function of other views

Comment: ya it works fine., but when i come back to the previous view, navigation bar shows black space for that screen and then it comes to previous view...i think it will not give a good user experience.i dont wanna see the black space....

Comment: just add [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; in -(void)ViewWillAppear of your initial view, that will  works again..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];` to each of the following views (which may be many), you could just add it to `- (void)viewWillDisappear` in your initial view... That way it will make sure to add it before leaving that view.
Make sure that you hide the navigation bar in `- (void)viewWillAppear`, so it'll hide it when you return to the initial view.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this and shorter in terms of code is:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

On the desired (hidden top bar) view controller.